# Importar archivos de Jaspersoft a Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

el asunto es que voy a dejar de utilizar Jaspersoft para empezar a usar Power Bi, y tengo 100 archivos Jasper que necesito poder importar a Power Bi, he estado investigando y comentan qué eso es imposible y que debe hacerse desde 0 todos los informes, existe alguna forma de poder utilizar esos reportes en Power Bi?

Comment: Si te refieres a reportes de Jasper, no hay traducción posible a Power BI. ¿o te refieres a archivos de datos?

Comment: Me refería a los reportes de Jasper, gracias por el comentario.